# Unable to connect to geth via web3.py

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, web3.py

I'm launching geth with following command:

```
geth --testnet --syncmode="full" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "localhost" --rpc
```

But when I'm trying to interact with geth by this python code

```
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
w3.eth.getBlock(123)
```

I'm getting `Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused` error
I also tried to use `--rpcport` argument but it doesn't helped too

Comment: I need to know if there is a way that when an action is executed in the blockchain from a front, the value of an intelligent contract that has eth balance and not metamask is discounted. Example a voting system, the end user (the one who votes), has to have a metamask installed ?, can the action be scheduled to be deducted from a contract? Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Are you sure that you are posted it in a proper place?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27649)

Comment: Silly question time: are you definitely running geth on the same machine as your web3 code is running on?

Comment: No, I'm running it from the different docker container and now can access geth by external IP. But still cant access by container's name even if writing it in `--rpccorsdomain="http://container_name"` argument